# both nfs and smb? or just use smb?

Tags: nfs, file-sharing, smb

If I want a nix share to be used by windows and other nix boxes should I just use smb for everything or should I use nfs aswell just for the nix boxes?

Comment: That is your decision, and will be made by your needs. I use nfs by choice, and use samba for more restricted (as in limited) access, so I use both as I find it fits my needs.  There are a lot of things I found a hassle on samba (so I'd go the nfs route for sure), but your use will likely differ to my own.

Comment: you are asking for an opinion and the answer is that it is good to have choices and both have advantages. Personally, although NFS works with windows, I prefer samba in a mixed windows / linux environments. I agree with @guiverc , samba feels more secure / restricted access.

Comment: essentially it's my network storage share that I want to be accessible for all systems on my network. it's just bulk raw data.  offline install files and so on.  I have a mixture on Windows and Linux systems and while it's probably lazy I just like to have a common dumping ground for everything so I can always access it from any system. its sounding like SMB is the way to go so all my ADDS  GPO's work no matter what system i'm on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use SMB if you need to differentiate access rights for different users or user groups, and at the same time need to give `sudo` right at least for some users.

Under NFS, a sudo-capable user can use `sudo su` to impersonate any other user with the known name, gaining potentially unauthorized access (or, say, write access when only read access should be granted). While the root squash prevents from impersonating the root, it does not prevent from impersonating just another user.

NFS may be easier to setup and its limitations are not always relevant (say if all have read access for all content that is written or updated not via NFS). However as you need to use SMB anyway, it may be simpler to have everything SMB only. This may also help later against the argument to ditch all Linux workstations as "insecure".

Comment: I don't agree .. you should use NFS under Linux/Unix if you want seamless integration with user / group / access rights. If users has sudo rights, tthey can remount the SMB shares with the rights they want.

Comment: Hopefully not if they do not have sudo rights on the SMB server.

Comment: I have a mixture on Windows and Linux systems and while it's probably lazy I just like to have a common dumping ground for everything so I can always access it from any system. its sounding like SMB is the way to go so all my ADDS GPO's work no matter what system i'm on.